# Destop shortcut to run access with an mdw file option fails

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-access

The shortcut target contains:

> "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\My Bases\Tootling_Music[1].mdb" /wrkgrp
>   "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\My Bases\pd1.mdw"

Access reports:

> Couldn't find file 'C:\Users\Peter\Documents\My1'. This file is
>   required for startup.

I have tried various varieties of database and mdw file locations but always get an mdw ref ending with 1 and the same access error message.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What version of Access are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do applies to Access 2003 and earlier databases. Assuming that is the case since you are pointing to an `mdb` file, what I see right off is that you are missing the initial path to `ACCESS.EXE`.

Your shortcut needs to include the path to Access. It should look something like this;

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.exe" "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\My Bases\Tootling_Music[1].mdb" /WRKGRP "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\My Bases\pd1.mdw"
```

Obviously, you need to use the proper path to your installed version.

Comment: Other bases without a need to specify a particular mdw file run perfectly without the prog path. In Office on Windows 10 it is hard to find the executable program anyway, where is it?

Comment: However the shortcut worke after after tracking ACCESS down (folder search didn't find it!) it was in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE". Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to get it working. If this is an acceptable answer, please choose the check mark to the left so others will know your question has an accepted answer.

Comment: To expand a bit I have been using a database on a Vista machine Access 2003 but on a recent windows update the machine was wiped out! Now I have a Windows10 machine with Access2016. I have been trying to restore some old bases that had mdw type security. This is a big problem which I am still grappling with.